# Can you removed crossfire cards in Extraction?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The Crossfire mission allows players to remove crossfire cards when defeating all enemies and thus ending the scene. Does Extraction ever allow the removal of any crossfire cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the extraction mission there is no way for a crossfire card to be removed. In all missions it will be clearly spelled out in the rules when a card can be removed. Part of the difficulty of an extraction mission is the ever increasing crossfire level which is balanced by the fact that you do not need to defeat all obstacles just survive for seven rounds.